# Prove that if the length of the maximal simple odd cycle in $G$ is $k$, then $\chi(G)\leq k+1$.

Tags: graph-theory

How can I prove that if the length of the maximal simple odd cycle in $G$ is $k$, then $\chi(G)\leq k+1$, when $\chi(G)$ is chromatic number of $G$?

My attempt to prove it looks like this: we can color any cycle of length $k$ in $k$ colors. Consider any vertex $u$ that is associated with a cycle of maximum length, and color it in $\text{MEX}$ ${v_i}$, when $v_i$ are all vertices of the cycle connected with $u$. If there are $2$ vertices with color $k+1$, we have odd cycle with length equals $k+2$. Next, consider other vertices that are not connected with a vertex in the cycle. If this vertex lies in another cycle, $\chi(G)$ is $\leq k+1$, and if it's in symple path, we can color this simple path too. How can I formalize this?

Comment: This link may be of interest in the meanwhile.  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/142873/chromatic-number-of-a-simple-graph-whose-length-of-the-longest-odd-cycle-is-2k1